# trying to use useState with types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

interface orderInformation {
    customer: number;
    picklePrice: number;
    breadPrice: number;

}

interface ComponentState
{
    customer: number;
    picklePrice: number;
    breadPrice: number;
}

export default class pickleSandwich extends Component<orderInformation,ComponentState> {

    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(0);

//Get information for the user
getInfo = orderInformation => {
        orderInformation.preventDefault();


      };

render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
}
}
```

I am currently learning typescript, however I cannot find any place with a good example with my needs. All I can find are string examples and in this case I am using type number.
    Trying to use React Hooks in order to consume this information.

Comment: what is the problem? not sure you should be using hooks at all with `class` syntax

Comment: you are not able to use hooks in class

Comment: It's pretty unclear what problem you're having. Can you explain it more clearly? As someone else said, your immediate problem is that you can't use hooks inside of a class. Read the "rules of hooks" here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use hooks that is the way:

```
import React from 'react'

interface orderInformation {
    customer: number;
    picklePrice: number;
    breadPrice: number;

}

interface ComponentState {
    customer: number;
    picklePrice: number;
    breadPrice: number;
}

const PickleSandwich = (props:orderInformation) =>  {

    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState<ComponentState>("valid_state");

    //Get information for the user
    getInfo = orderInformation => {
        orderInformation.preventDefault();
    };

    return <div />

}
```

but if you go to use class, you are in the right path but in class you are not able to use hooks, then you need to use:

```
state = {your_state}
```